# Finding position/movement of a particle along a horizontal coordinate line given a specific function?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

One of the practice problems in my book states: **A particle moves according to a law of motion $s=f(t) __ [m], t>=0$, where $t$ is seconds. A particle moves along a horizontal coordinate line in such a way that its position at time $t$ is specified by $s(t)=t^3-12t^2+36t-30$**:

- a) When is the particle standing still?
- b) When does the particle move left?
- c) When does the particle move right?
- d) Find the total distance traveled during the first 10 seconds.

(If I'm understanding this correctly) I would plug in $0$ for $t$ to answer (a) and then do the same with $10$ for $t$ to answer (d), but how do I answer (b) & (c)? Or am I missing something with (a) & (d) as well?

---

**EDIT**:

Taking Ross's suggestion, for (a) I have the following:

$s(t)=t^3-12t^2+36t-30$
$s'(t)=3t^2-24t+36$
$s'(0)=3(0)^2-24(0)+36$
$s'(0)=36$?

Still not sure what to do in order to answer (b), (c), (d)?

Comment: Use \geq to get $\geq$. And what were you hoping to get with "__"?

Comment: Thanks! For the "__" I was just trying to appropriately show the spacing before the $[m]$.

Answer (score 1):

Draw the graph of s'(t) ; positive means it moves right; zero means stand-still. negative means it moves to left.

Find s(10) for distance traveled.

Comment: The integral should be of $|s'(t)|$  You want to integrate the speed, but need the absolute value bars to count negative velocity as positive.

Comment: Apologies. That was in error. You need only to directly evaluate s(t) at t=10.

Comment: That measures the distance from start to finish, but the total distance traveled should count the period from $t=2$ to $t=6$ as positive, not negative.

Comment: Understanding the word "total";  When referring to back and forth motion along a straight line, if a particle is moving in harmonic oscillations from center  with amplitude 1, some  100 times, length traveled is 400, but total distance covered  on the line is zero.I understood it as displacement, especially in a context of the example given that attempts to teach derivatives and calculus to beginners with a tag.. algebra pre-calculus.

Answer (score 0):

The particle is standing still when the velocity is zero. The velocity is the time derivative of the position, so for a, you want $s'(t)=0$. For b and c you want the derivative to have the proper sign. The total distance traveled comes from integrating the absolute value of the velocity to account for back and forth motion

Comment: please see my Edit above. I've worked out (a) -- can you verify if correct? I'm still not sure how to proceed though on (b), (c), and (d).

Comment: No, you want $s'(t)=0$.  You took the derivative correctly, but now you want $0=3t^2-24t+36$

Comment: I don't understand what I'm supposed to do with $0=3t^2-24t+36$?

Comment: Solve it for $t$. That is the time the velocity is zero. You need to read up on the relationship between position, velocity, and acceleration.

Comment: I'm still totally lost. I got as far as $-12=t^2-8t$?

Comment: It is a quadratic equation, which you can factor as $3(t-2)(t-6)=0$ Have you seen those before?  If you can take a derivative, I would have thought so.

Comment: I'm in Calculus now, and took Pre-calclus (Online) last year. There are some concepts I did NOT master in pre-calculus -- and I've always had issues with figuring out Factoring. So I now have $3(t-2)(t-6)$.. now what?

Comment: When a product is zero, at least one of the terms is zero.  This shows that the derivative is zero at $t=2$ and $t=6$, so these are the times the particle is standing still.  The particle is moving left when the derivative is positive.  When is that?

Comment: If you are trying to do calculus, you need to be able to solve a quadratic equation.  You also need to be able to see from the factored representation where the quadratic is positive or negative.  The quadratic formula is another route to the factorization-it is *important* to see why this is so.